# Why does adding custom build step in Visual Studio Qt project with Qt add-in stop automatic MOC and UIC steps?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, custom-build-step

I have a Visual Studio Qt project using the Visual Studio Qt Add-in.  The Add-in automatically creates a *Custom Build Tool* rule for .ui files and for each header file that has classes with the Q_OBJECT declaration to run the UIC and MOC respectively.

This all works perfectly until I add a *Custom Build Tool* rule for the project as a whole.  In this instance, the rule is specific to the *Release* build and invokes code signing and is set to *Execute after: **Build***.  With this configuration, the *Debug* build works correctly, but the *Release* does not *automatically* execute the MOC or UIC.  I can right click the Q_OBJECT headers and .ui files in the project browser and manually force a *Compile* for all necessary files, and they are correctly MOC'd and UIC'd and can then build, but a rebuild or build after clean always fails.

Why has adding a project *Custom build rule* for the project appear to have suppressed the *Custom Build Tool* rules associated .ui and Q_OBJECT headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your custom build step, set "execute after" to BuildGenerateSources.

This is represented in the vcxproj-file by adding the line

```
<CustomBuildAfterTargets Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">BuildGenerateSources</CustomBuildAfterTargets>
```

to the `<PropertyGroup>` block

Comment: Thanks - although the moment has passed!  In the end I solved the problem laterally by making it a *pre-build step* in the installer project to which the application is a build dependency.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing the same thing by extending the prebuild step I already had in place, but luckily there is a way to solve this properly.